# How to present modal view Controller from tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I can't delegate my custom Button. please help

**1****TabBarController**

```
func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

if let count = self.tabBar.items?.count {
    let i = floor(Double(count / 2))
    self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers?[Int(i)]
}

}
```

**2****ViewController**

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

print(tabBarController.tabBarItem.title)

return true
}
```

don't print if i touch my custom Button. Another 4 buttons work OK

Comment: Have you set delegate?

Comment: Yes. In viewDidLoad I wrote self.tabBarController.delegate = self.

Comment: Does the `print` method works if you tap on another item of the tabBar? I think when you programmatically change the `selectedViewController`it doesn't call the delegate method.

Comment: If I tap another items of the tabbar it's work very well, doesn't work only my custom button